# How does minReadySeconds affect readiness probe?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Let's say I have a deployment template like this

```
spec:
  minReadySeconds: 15
  readinessProbe:
    failureThreshold: 3
    httpGet:
      path: /
      port: 80
      scheme: HTTP
    initialDelaySeconds: 20
    periodSeconds: 20
    successThreshold: 1
    timeoutSeconds: 5
```

How will this affect the newly versions of my app? Will the `minReadySeconds` and `initialDelaySeconds` count at the same time? Will the `initialDelaySeconds` come first then `minReadySeconds`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From Kubernetes [Deployment documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#min-ready-seconds):

> `.spec.minReadySeconds` is an optional field that specifies the minimum number of seconds for which a newly created Pod should be ready without any of its containers crashing, for it to be considered available. This defaults to 0 (the Pod will be considered available as soon as it is ready). To learn more about when a Pod is considered ready, see [Container Probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes)

So your newly created app pod have to be ready for `.spec.minReadySeconds` seconds to be considered as available.

> `initialDelaySeconds`: Number of seconds after the container has started before liveness or readiness probes are initiated.

So `initialDelaySeconds` comes before `minReadySeconds`.

Lets say, container in the pod has started at `t` seconds. Readiness probe will be initiated at `t+initialDelaySeconds` seconds. Assume Pod become ready at `t1` seconds(`t1 > t+initialDelaySeconds`). So this pod will be available after `t1+minReadySeconds` seconds.

Comment: So in short Readiness probe's `initialDelaySeconds` then `minReadySecoonds`. after those two then will my app serve traffic

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada yes.

Comment: Not really - you are assuming that immediately after `initialDelaySeconds` the readiness check will pass.

Comment: From my experimentations the new Pod can serve traffic immediately after it passes readiness check, even before `minReadySeconds` is elapsed. `minReadySeconds` seems to be only used by the deployment strategy.  I couldn't find exact behavior in the documentation unfortunately